# New django project: Cannot import name connections

Tags: python, django

I'm having a problem with Django. If you could help me, I'd very much appreciate it.

So, I've found lots of people with a similar problem, but none of the "solutions" work for me. I'm learning how to use django and I've successfully installed it.

But, I get an error when executing the import from the **init**.py file:

```
from django.db import connections
```

Here's the error:

```
raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'TestProject.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): cannot import name connections
```

The containing django folder is included on my PYTHONPATH, and my file structure looks like this:

```
TestProject
--manage.py
--TestProject
----__init__.py
----settings.py
    etc.
```

This is my manage.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python import os import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "TestProject.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I don't really know how to troubleshoot this. I'm also new to Python, so forgive me if this is completely obvious to someone else.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What happens when you try to import the same statement by going to python shell under your virtual env manually? you need DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE value in OS env variable, you can do it by export command. What version of django you using?

Comment: Can you go to `/TestProject` and do `python`. Then, try `import settings` to see if you can import the file. If you see any errors then that explains it.

Comment: So, import settings gave me an error:
"ImportError: No module named settings".

Any ideas on how to get python to find the settings?

Comment: in your django shell, what happens if you print `import sys; sys.path` ?

Comment: It gives me several filepaths: C:\\Python27\\lib C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk C:\\Python27\\ 
C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django

Comment: This could be due to circular import. You have `TestProject` as root and `TestProject` as app name, right? Redo and start the project as `TestProject` and your first app something like `TestCore`.

Comment: @kechdaop Have you changed anything on `settings.py` (check you don't have there any syntax error)? What happens if you do what Simeon suggested with `import TestProject.settings`?

Comment: @limelights So, I'm using Aptana Studio. I didn't explicitly set the project and app names separately; Aptana did that. I assumed it would know how to properly configure a new project. Maybe it doesn't....I'll try that, though. 

Salem, I haven't touched the settings.py myself, although the DATABASES setting did get configured during creation. I did try Simeon's suggestion, as noted in my first comment. It gave me this error: ImportError: No module named settings

Comment: @limelights I tried your suggestion. I created a new package with a different name, but got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird quirk indeed. I found the following to work in my program:

1. Import django settings.
2. Set the default environment.
3. ACCESS e.g. SITE_ID (or another property, but just use e.g. SITE_ID) through settings.
4. Finally, you should be able to import.

E.g.

```
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

settings.SITE_ID
```

or use another variable like `DEBUG`; note.. this line does nothing.. it just accesses the settings and seems to 'activate' the environment. You could also do a simple print statement like `print settings.SITE_ID`, but that's not necessary.)

```
from myapp.models import MyModel, MyOtherModel
```

If you do everything in that order.. well it worked for me! The magic happens when you access an actual setting before you do the import of a model.

I think this might be a bug/error in Django 1.5

Comment: Signatures are against the stack overflow style/use guidelines.  If you want to share that information; put it in your profile.